# AVG antivirus not working

Tags: software-installation, antivirus

I want to install AVG 2012 antivirus on my Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit). When I install it with Gdebi it gets installed without any problem, but when I try to start avg antivirus form terminal by typing the below command, it returns an error:

```
$ sudo avgctl --startIt show following error message:
/usr/bin/avgctl: 17: exec: /opt/avg/av/bin/avgctl: not found
```

When I check the files manually they are there. I don't understand what the problem is; my avg antivirus was working fine on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

I thinks so you have to install ia32-libs package.

Full steps are as follows:

This works for both 32 and 64 bit versions of Ubuntu 10.10 and above.

**Step 1** Download the linux version (.deb file) from [here](http://free.avg.com/download.prd-alf)

**Step 2** Run following command to install debian package
**Note: 64-bit versions of Ubuntu need ia32-libs, or similar package before install**

```
sudo dpkg -i avg2012flx-r1795-a5274.i386.deb
```

Expected output is as follows

```
Selecting previously unselected package avg2012flx.
(Reading database ... 153531 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking avg2012flx (from avg2012flx-r1795-a5274.i386.deb) ...
Setting up avg2012flx (2012.1795) ...
Installing 'avgd' service initscripts...
Registering 'avgd' service to runlevels...
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/avgd ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20avgd -> ../init.d/avgd
   /etc/rc1.d/K20avgd -> ../init.d/avgd
   /etc/rc6.d/K20avgd -> ../init.d/avgd
   /etc/rc2.d/S20avgd -> ../init.d/avgd
   /etc/rc3.d/S20avgd -> ../init.d/avgd
   /etc/rc4.d/S20avgd -> ../init.d/avgd
   /etc/rc5.d/S20avgd -> ../init.d/avgd
Registering with license: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
AVG command line controller
Copyright (c) 2012 AVG Technologies CZ

License was successfully changed.
Operation successful.
Please do configuration with /opt/avg/av/bin/avgsetup
Generating unique user id
Processing command line ...
Cfg file not specified using /opt/avg/av/cfg/diagcfg.xml.
New installation ID succesffully generated.
 * Starting avgd ...                                                     [ ok ]
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

**Step 3** Reboot the PC to initialize AVG. Alternatively you could run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/avgd start
```

**Step 4** Run following command to update virus database

```
sudo avgupdate
```

Expected output is as follows

```
AVG command line update
Copyright (c) 2012 AVG Technologies CZ

Running update.
Initializing...
Analyzing...
Downloading file:  u12iavi5350u5270wc.bin                      1 /  1    2.01 M
Analyzing...
Preparing installation...
Updating...
100% [===================================>]

Update was successfully completed.
```

**Useful Commands**

To Start AVG Anti-Virus run following command

```
sudo avgctl --start
```

For Scanning a Virus

```
avgscan -H /desire_folder
avgscan --heur /
```

To Update a Virus Databases

```
sudo avgupdate --priority 2
sudo avgupdate -p 3
sudo avgupdate -p 4
```

Source : [How to Install AVG Free Antivirus Software on Ubuntu 12.10, 12.04](http://www.techienote.com/2012/10/how-to-install-avg-free-antivirus-software-on-ubuntu-12-10-12-04.html)

Comment: No sir, after registering with license xxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxx it shows following error  /usr/bin/avgctl: 17: exec: /opt/avg/av/bin/avgctl: not found

Comment: xxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxx is not the actual license. It comes with the installation. BTW run "apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install ia32-libs" to install necessary libraries and then try "avgctl"

Comment: Thank You Sir, for your reply,I had already installed ia32-libs and now my avg antivirus is working fine.

Comment: Kindly accept the ans if the above steps helped you to solve your problem

Comment: I had better luck installing gcc-4.6-multilib (which installs ia32-libs) on Ubuntu 12.04: `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6-multilib`